# TypeScript - Representar o resto dos parâmetros de um componente em uma Interface

Tags: typescript, react, react-native

Tenho um componente de `Input` que utiliza o `TextInput` do React Native. Este componente deve aceitar a propriedade `append`, e qualquer outra propriedade que lhe for passada será atribuída ao componente `TextInput`:

```
interface InputProps {
  append: string;
}

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({append, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Append>{append}</Append>

      <TextInput {...props} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Utilização:

```
const Home: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Input append="R$" placeholder="0,00" />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Neste caso, a propriedade `placeholder` é destacada como inválida por que ela não existe na interface que define as propriedades aceitas pelo componente `Input`.

> Property 'placeholder' does not exists on type 'InstrinsicAttributes & InputProps & {children?: ReactNode;} **TS(2322)**

Já segui algumas sugestões como utilizar o `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>`, mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo tente passe as demais propriedades que não quer declarar no interface por fora da estruturação, assim:

```
interface InputProps {
  append: string;
}

const Input: React.FC<InputProps> = ({append}: InputProps, ...props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Append>{append}</Append>

      <TextInput {...props} />
    </>
  )
}
```